# Any Non-Singleton PHP PDO Db Connection Examples?

Tags: php, database

Are there any good examples of non-Singleton PHP PDO Dbfactory or connection classes people can point me in the direction, or perhaps even briefly illustrate.

I am interested in learning both support of persistent connections as well as multiple instantiation. Right now, mostly I am finding Singleton use examples.

My goal is to :

(a) read db connection info ('dsn') info from a config file.

(b) instantiate a new instance

(c) return instance upon successful connection

(d) perform crud ** or ** trigger exception handling and event logging on errors

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new instance of PDO:

```
$connectionOne = new PDO(" --- dsn --- ", $username, $password, [
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
]);

$connectionTwo = new PDO(" --- another dsn ---", $anotherUser, $anotherPassword);
```

Just take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.construct.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.drivers.php) for your driver-specific options.

Comment: Although very simple, this answer is actually the best possible example how to make a non singleton PDO.